# Scraping tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm getting my BeautifulSoup and python bearings by walking through the process of scraping a friend's (structured, if clunky) website, with the long term goal of migrating the whole thing into a content management system.

If I pull out exactly one cell (`soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bicyclepaintings.com/archive/index.html")`) in the console with:

```
cell = soup.find_all('td',{'valign':'bottom'})[3]
```

I can play around with pulling out substrings. These all work fine: `cell.br.next_sibling`, `cell.find('b').text`. But when I try to loop through all the cells with a for loop:

```
def parse_archive(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    paintings = []
    for cell in soup.find_all('td',{'valign':'bottom'}):
        painting_title = cell.find('b').text
        painting_media = cell.br.next_sibling 
        record = painting_title, painting_media
        paintings.append(record)
    return paintings
```

I get an attribute error (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`). I can get some of the same information by looping back through:

```
    for item in cell.find_all('b'):
        painting_title = item.text
```

But I don't see a way to get at the sibling to `<br/>` and (more to the point) I don't understand why it works if I pull one item out but not if I try to access them through a for loop. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the site you are trying to scrape has a bunch of `<td>` tags at the end that do not contain a `<b>` tag:

```
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
<td nowrap valign="bottom"><!-- painting image -->
<p><font><!-- painting data, use &quot; for quotes --></font></p></td>
```

You just need to modify your code to ignore these tags:

```
for cell in soup.find_all('td',{'valign':'bottom'}):
    title = cell.find('b')
    if title is None:
        continue
    painting_title = title.text
    painting_media = cell.br.next_sibling 
    record = painting_title, painting_media
    paintings.append(record)
```

As far as matching the `painting_media` you can just use:

```
painting_media = list(cell.br.children)
painting_media = painting_media[0].strip() if painting_media else ''
```

Comment: Works. Would the `var = one.thing if thing else '' syntax work in place of "if title is None: continue"?

Comment: It would not work since title needs to be a beautiful soup tag.

Comment: I wound up using `if len(graph.contents) > 4:` inside of `for graph in cell.find_all('font'):` to rule out the blank cells.